# Metallb with nginx ingress controller on minkube keeps resetting external IP for ingress

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, metallb

A MCVE example is here: https://github.com/chrissound/k8s-metallb-nginx-ingress-minikube
(just run `./init.sh` and `minikube addons enable ingress`).

The IP assigned to the ingress keeps getting reset, I don't know what is causing it? Do I need additional configuration perhaps?

```
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces                 
NAMESPACE       NAME          HOSTS         ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
chris-example   app-ingress   example.com   192.168.122.253   80, 443   61m
```

And a minute later:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME          HOSTS         ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
chris-example   app-ingress   example.com             80, 443   60m
```

---

In terms of configuration I've just applied:

```
# metallb
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.7.3/manifests/metallb.yaml

# nginx
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml
```

---

ingress controller logs logs:

```
I0714 22:00:38.056148       7 event.go:258] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"chris-example", Name:"app-ingress", UID:"cbf3b5bf-a67a-11e9-be9a-a4cafa3aa171", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"8681", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress chris-example/app-ingress
I0714 22:01:19.153298       7 event.go:258] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"chris-example", Name:"app-ingress", UID:"cbf3b5bf-a67a-11e9-be9a-a4cafa3aa171", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"8743", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress chris-example/app-ingress
I0714 22:01:38.051694       7 status.go:296] updating Ingress chris-example/app-ingress status from [{192.168.122.253 }] to []
I0714 22:01:38.060044       7 event.go:258] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"chris-example", Name:"app-ingress", UID:"cbf3b5bf-a67a-11e9-be9a-a4cafa3aa171", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"8773", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress chris-example/app-ingress
```

And the metallb controller logs:

```
{"caller":"main.go:72","event":"noChange","msg":"service converged, no change","service":"kube-system/kube-dns","ts":"2019-07-14T21:58:39.656725017Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:73","event":"endUpdate","msg":"end of service update","service":"kube-system/kube-dns","ts":"2019-07-14T21:58:39.656741267Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:49","event":"startUpdate","msg":"start of service update","service":"chris-example/app-lb","ts":"2019-07-14T21:58:39.6567588Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:72","event":"noChange","msg":"service converged, no change","service":"chris-example/app-lb","ts":"2019-07-14T21:58:39.656842026Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:73","event":"endUpdate","msg":"end of service update","service":"chris-example/app-lb","ts":"2019-07-14T21:58:39.656873586Z"}
```

---

As a test I deleted the deployment+daemonset relating to metallb:

```
kubectl delete deployment -n metallb-system controller
kubectl delete daemonset -n metallb-system speaker
```

And after the external IP is set, it'll once again reset...

Answer (score 3):

I was curious and recreated your case. I was able to properly expose the service.

First of all: you don't need to use minikube ingress addon when deploying your own NGINX. If you do, you have 2 ingress controllers in a cluster and it leads confusion later. Run: `minikube addons disable ingress`

Sidenote: You can see this confusion in the IP your ingress got assigned: `192.168.122.253` which is not in CIDR range `192.168.39.160/28` you defined in `configmap-metallb.yaml`.

---

You need to change service type of `ingress-nginx` to `LoadBalancer`. you can do this by running:

```
kubectl edit -n ingress-nginx service ingress-nginx
```

Additionally, you can change `app-lb` service to `NodePort`, since it doesn't need to be exposed outside of the cluster - ingress controller will take care of it.

---

#### Explanation

It's easier to think about `Ingress` object as of `ConfigMap`, rather than `Service`.

MetalLB takes configuration you provided in `ConfigMap` and waits for IP request API call. When it gets one it provides IP form the CIDR range you specified.

In a similar way, ingress controller (NGINX in your case) takes configuration described in `Ingress` object and uses it to rout traffic to desired place in the cluster.

Then `ingress-nginx` service is exposed outside of the cluster with assigned IP.

Inbound traffic is directed by Ingress controller (NGINX), based on rules described in `Ingress` object to a service in font of your application.

#### Diagram

```
Inbound
traffic
   ++     +---------+
   ||     |ConfigMap|
   ||     +--+------+
   ||        |
   ||        | CIDR range to provision
   ||        v
   ||     +--+----------+
   ||     |MetalLB      |               +-------+
   ||     |Load balancer|               |Ingress|
   ||     +-+-----------+               +---+---+
   ||       |                               |
   ||       |  External IP assigned         |Rules described in spec
   ||       |  to service                   |
   ||       v                               v
   ||    +--+--------------------+      +---+------------------+
   ||    |                       |      |  Ingress Controller  |
   |---->+ ingress-nginx service +----->+      (NGINX pod)     |
   +---->|                       +----->+                      |
         +-----------------------+      +----------------------+
                                                    ||
                                                    VV
                                          +-----------------+
                                          | Backend service |
                                          | (app-lb)        |
                                          |                 |
                                          +-----------------+
                                                   ||
                                                   VV
                                          +--------------------+
                                          | Backend pod        |
                                          | (httpbin)          |
                                          |                    |
                                          +--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice diagram. What I don't understand is why we need Metallb as the same can be achieved by ingress service...

Comment: MetalLB works at layer 4 (IP + Port), Ingress works at layer 7 (hostname, URL, HTTP header, etc).